# Action Cable and Ionic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ionic-framework, actioncable

I have a Rails Application in production environment and now I need to develop a Mobile App as a "frontend" for the same system.

We are already building an API, but many users will be able to change data at the same time, therefore, would be nice some real time integration.

Would it be possible to integrate Action Cable in an Ionic App? Is there any other good alternative to Action Cable + Ionic?

Regards

Comment: have you discovered yet how to do it? regards

Answer (score 1):

YES, all you need is to include the actioncable javascript into your ionic project.
https://github.com/mwalsher/actioncable-js

Just create a service, or even use an angular-ready actioncable package like this: https://github.com/angular-actioncable/angular-actioncable

Bottom line, its just javascript. this is all client side stuff so it doesn't matter if you're using ionic or any other client side framework, as long as you have the server side setup in your rails app to connect to.